# bottle.py seems to strip some headers

Tags: python, python-requests, bottle

Using python requests I sent headers that included {'foo': 'bar'}.

Sending code was like:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'foo':'bar'})
session.post('http://localhost:8000/whatever', json={a=1, b=2})
```

I also tried it without the session and with explicit headers={'foo':'bar'}.  Same result.

In my receiving method of form:

```
@app.post('/whatever')
def do_something():
  do_something_with(request.get_header('foo'))
```

I find that foo is missing.  Why would that be?  I am certain that it was there in the sending session.

Comment: In case it matters this was under python3.5

Answer (score 0):

oops.  I over-simplified.  I had a header 'xyz_client'.  It did not get through.  When I changed it to 'xyz-client' it did.

Comment: If you fixed your own issue, then it's probably best to just delete your question :)

Comment: Are you saying that header keys with _ (underscore) characters seem to be stripped (by your browser?  by your HTTP daemon (web server), or by some other component in your software or networking stack)?

Comment: To be specific I was using requests to a bottle.py web server.